# UK travel document for business owner

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm applying for the UK standard visitor visa for the first time with my wife and kid to travel to the UK in the summer. I'm self-employed in India and own a business to prove the business and income I've:

- GST registration document
- Business bank account statement
- latest office rental agreement
- Income tax returns(self filed)

do I need anything else? My friend suggested a letter from CA, but I do my own taxes and hence I calculate and make my own **balance sheet** and **profit and loss statements** for each year, should I upload those as well or any other document that I might have missed regarding my income?

Comment: Don’t forget your own bank statements. The goal for them is to see the money ending up in your hands.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse  @jcaron I'll provide my personal bank statement and property information but my main concern is regarding P&L statements and a letter from CA regarding profit earned in business.

Comment: Are accounts filed with a government organisation in your country? If so a copy of those coming from them may be helpful. Otherwise if you just provide accounts you've compiled yourself they don't have much reason to trust them. I think we've seen a few times people around here with a response from the UK ECO saying that self-filed income tax returns don't count for anything and they needed something more tangible, but I don't remember the details. You may want to search for such previous questions for more info.

Comment: Any governmental documents confirming the existence of the company will help

Comment: @Jcaron I use the same P&L statements and balance sheet documents for filing my income tax every year, and that is accepted by the government. I've last 2-3 years of income tax returns(self-assessed) and my last 6 months of business bank statement and personal bank statement clearly show profit getting transferred every month and that amount matches income tax return filed and P&L statment.

Comment: @Nicolas I've got a GST registration document provided by the central government of India and also a professional tax registration document from the state government.

Comment: You might review [this Question and Answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) for more information about records, including business records. Be persistent, there's a lot of material there.

Comment: As a self-employed business owner you might want to consider how you'll assure the ECO that your business will survive in your absence so that you'll have something to return to.